# how can we get all transaction according date(timestamp) filter

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

**What I have**
1. I have setup my own private blockchain.
2. mining started on my node

**What I want**
1. I want to know all transaction object which executed last one or 24 hour and their total ether value.

Answer (score 3):

You can check all blocks downwards from the current while checking block timestamp. Here is a simple node.js script:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));


const date = new Date();
const minTimestamp = date.setHours(date.getHours() - 1) / 1000;
console.log('Retreiving all transactions from', date);


const {currentBlock, highestBlock} = web3.eth.syncing;
if(currentBlock < highestBlock) {
  console.log('Warning! Node is not synced:\n', web3.eth.syncing);
}

let blockNum = web3.eth.blockNumber;
const transactions = [];

while(true) {
  const block = web3.eth.getBlock(blockNum);
  if(block.timestamp < minTimestamp) break;
  transactions.push.apply(transactions, block.transactions);
  --blockNum;
}

console.log('Retreived', transactions.length, 'transactions');


const total = transactions.reduce(
  (sum, tx) => web3.eth.getTransaction(tx).value.plus(sum),
  new web3.BigNumber(0)
);

console.log('Total value is', web3.fromWei(total, 'ether').toNumber(), 'Ether');
```